# Access from parent component to child component when the child form is dirty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I have created a pending changes guard which alerts my users, if there has been changes made to the form and warns them before navigating away.

This all works fine but I have a child component on the page which is rendered using a selector, this component has a form on also.

How can I access this form from my guard to check if the form is dirty?

Guard:

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../components/confirm/confirm.component';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export interface FormComponent {
    form: FormGroup;
}

export class PreventUnsavedChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<FormComponent> {

constructor(@Inject(DialogService) private dialogService: DialogService) { }

canDeactivate(component: FormComponent): Promise<boolean> {

    if (component.form.dirty) {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

            this.dialogService.addDialog(ConfirmComponent, {
                title: 'Unsaved Changes',
                message: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to navigate away?'
            })
                .subscribe((isConfirmed) => {
                    return resolve(isConfirmed);
                });
        });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether that child component is getting used in some other place in your application ??

Comment: If its not getting used anywhere else, then remove the `form` from child component and use the parent component `form` inside child component. In this way if input fields in child becomes dirty, then parent will also become dirty.

Comment: @SameerK can you explain abit more what you mean by use the parent compoent inside the child?

Comment: I mean, pass the parent form as input to child component. Then child component needs to bind the input field to that form. If child's input fields becomes dirty, then parent form will become dirty. So in that you do not need to access child form in your guard.

Comment: @SameerK Gotcha, if you put that as an answer I will mark it for you as I have no got it working following your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parent form as input to child component. Then child component needs to bind the input field to that form. If child's input fields becomes dirty, then parent form will become dirty. So in that you do not need to access child form in your guard. For example,

**Parent Component ts**

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
private addEmailItemForm : FormGroup;
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.parentComponentForm = this._fb.group({});
    }
}
```

**Parent Component's HTML**

```
<child-component
   [parentForm]="parentComponentForm"
</child-component>
```

**Child Component ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;      
   let inputFieldControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
   this.parentForm.addControl(this.inputFieldControlName, inputFieldControl);
}
```

**Child Component's HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="parentForm.controls[inputFieldControlName]">
```

Comment: This answer is confusing because you can't do the lines 

```let inputFieldControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);```
```this.parentForm.addControl(this.inputFieldControlName, inputFieldControl);```

in that context.